# Ruby regexp - get facebook video id from different urls with a unique regexp

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I would like to extract video ids from potentially different URLs

```
https://www.facebook.com/{page-name}/videos/{video-id}/
https://www.facebook.com/{username}/videos/{video-id}/
https://www.facebook.com/video.php?id={video-id}
https://www.facebook.com/video.php?v={video-id}
```

How can I retrieve the video ids with a single ruby regex?

I haven't managed to convert this to Ruby regex but I (partially) managed to write it in standard JS regex:

```
^(https?://www\.facebook\.com/(?:video\.php\?v=\d+|.*?/videos/\d+))$
```

When I run the following code in Ruby it gives me an error:

```
text = "https://www.facebook.com/pili.morillo.56/videos/352355988613922/"
id = text.gsub( ^(https?://www\.facebook\.com/(?:video\.php\?v=\d+|.*?/videos/\d+))$ )
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code you've written so far.

Comment: Something like this: `/(?<=videos\/)[^\/]+?(?=\/|$)|(?<=id=)[^&]+?(?=&|$)|(?<=v=)[^&]+?(?=&|$)/` might work? are you sure you need them all in 1 regexp?

Comment: Maybe [`[\/=]([^\/=]+)(?:[\/]|$)$`](http://rubular.com/r/4aaiFfyfMu)

Comment: @scagood, yes the urls can be one of those 4 types i mentioned. i need to have a method that extracts a video-id whatever one of the four formats I run into for an object

Comment: are there lines which do not match any of these 4 types?

Comment: @Mathieu - Here is an example of the regex I show earlier, is that what you're looking for? - http://rubular.com/r/FhuluxhrSr

Comment: Does it always end on `{video-id}/` or `={video-id}`?

Comment: The brackets are to say that it is a variable. Yes @fourth bird always one of the two.

Comment: so `text.match(/.*\{([^}]+)/) and puts $1` would work? `/.*facebook.*video.*[=\/]\{([^}]+)/` might be better qualifier if there are other kind of lines

Comment: @Thefourthbird - I assumed, because it's facebook, there'll be a 'mess' of metadata in the url, for example `https://www.facebook.com/video.php?id={video-id}&trackingid={tracking-id}&referer=...` etc.

Comment: @all Will try to move forward based on your suggestions in a few hour

Comment: I'll make an explanation of my regex now, and post that as an answer in a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the regexp I came up with: `/(?<=\/videos\/)\d+?(?=\/|$)|(?<=[?&]id=)\d+?(?=&|$)|(?<=[?&]v=)\d+?(?=&|$)/`

Breaking this up we can get this:

```
(?<=\/videos\/)\d+(?=\/|$)|
(?<=[?&]id=)\d+(?=&|$)|
(?<=[?&]v=)\d+(?=&|$)
```

Each of the three options follow the following simple structure: `(?<=beforeMatch)target(?=afterMatch)`.
Here is the first as an example:

```
(?<=\/videos\/) # Positive lookbehind
\d+             # Matching the digits
(?=\/|$)        # Positive lookahead
```

So, this means, match `\d+` any digit, as long as it's preceeded by `\/videos\/` and followed by `\/` or it's the end of the line.

Therefore, we can match by 'id=', 'v=' or 'videos/'.

The full explaination:

```
(?<=\/videos\/) # Match as long as preceeded by '\/videos\/'
\d+             # Matching the id digits
(?=\/|$)        # As long as it's followed by '\/' or the EOL
|             # Or
(?<=[?&]id=)    # Match as long as preceeded by '?id' or  '&id'
\d+             #  Matching the id digits
(?=&|$)         # As long as it's followed by either '&' or the EOL
|             # Or
(?<=[?&]v=)     # Match as long as preceeded by '?v' or  '&v'
\d+             # Matching the id digits
(?=&|$)         # As long as it's followed by either '&' or the EOL
```

Where 'EOL' means end of line.

Answer (score 0):

```
RE = %r[https://www.facebook.com/(?:.+?/)?video(?:.*?[/=])(.+?)(?:/?\z)]
%w[
  https://www.facebook.com/{page-name}/videos/{video-id}/
  https://www.facebook.com/{username}/videos/{video-id}/
  https://www.facebook.com/video.php?id={video-id}
  https://www.facebook.com/video.php?v={video-id}
].map { |url| url[RE, 1] }
#⇒ ["{video-id}", "{video-id}", "{video-id}", "{video-id}"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You might use:

[`^https?:\/\/www\.facebook\.com\/.*?video(?:s|\.php.*?[?&](?:id|v)=)\/?([^\/&\n]+).*$`](http://rubular.com/r/p9DJ4P83AS)

**That would match**

Begin of the string and begin url

`^https?:\/\/www\.facebook\.com\/`

Followed by:

```
.*?          # Match any character zero or more times
video        # Match video
(?:          # Non capturing group
  s          # Match s
  |          # Or
  \.php      # Match .php
  .*?        # Match any character zero or more times         
  [?&]       # Match ? or &
  (?:id|v)=  # Match id or v in non capturing group followed by =
)            # Close non capturing group
\/?          # Match optional /
(            # Capturing group (group 1)
  [^\/&\n]+  # Match not / or & or newline
)            # Close capturing group
.*           # Match any character zero or more times
$            # End of the string
```

```
text = "https://www.facebook.com/pili.morillo.56/videos/352355988613922/"
id = text.gsub(/^https?:\/\/www\.facebook\.com\/.*?video(?:s|\.php.*?[?&](?:id|v)=)\/?([^\/&\n]+).*$/, "\\1")
puts id
```

That will result in: `352355988613922`

[Demo](http://rextester.com/KEZW17560)

Comment: thanks it worked and many thanks for the detailed explanation. I upvoted @scagood as it was the first one and working too.